# replace checkboxes with text input (select while typing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, replace

I'd like to hide my (very long) list of checkboxes and show a single text input where I'd like to type the labels. When the label I typed has been found, it should be confirmed (that is selected).

It should work as wordpress let the user choose the tags.
I'm thinking about something with jquery, but I didn't found anything until now.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var self = this
    var checkboxes = $(".checkbox")
    var filtered_checkboxes = checkboxes.filter(function (i, e) {
        return e.innerHTML.toLowerCase().match(self.value.toLowerCase());
    })
    checkboxes.not(filtered_checkboxes).hide();
    filtered_checkboxes.show();
    filtered_checkboxes.prop('checked', 'true')
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I was away so I can try them only today.

I will inform you about my tests.